# Is there any way to give spacing to <ion-grid>

Tags: ionic2

I wanted to give only vertical and horizontal space between grid cell. Is there any attribute to set space between grid cell?

Comment: Simply give it a class name and add styles to it

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
<ion-grid class="grid"></ion-grid>
```

and the the css:

```
.grid{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

And I'm pretty sure that styles are going to be applied too by only using a selector in css file:

```
ion-grid ion-row, ion-col{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Alternatively you can use padding instead of margin

Comment: I tried margin to <ion-grid> but not working. I wan space between rows and columns

Comment: Can you please update your question with your <ion> elements code

Comment: Try to play around with selectors. If you have something like ion-col/ion-row in your grid then try to add style to these selectors

Answer (score 0):

you can use the padding that ionic provide or what i will do to have more control is the following:
on the page.scss file

```
my-page ion-col{
     margin: 5px;
}
```